# Any source for learning phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am new to phonegap and I am searching for a source such as websites to learn how to use it.
I was searching on http://wiki.phonegap.com but there is only basic information such as installation of eclipse and sdk etc.
I need some source code for accessing contacts, camera, accelerometer.
Can someone guide me with links or some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - http://docs.phonegap.com/ : This will give you the insight of
>     PhoneGap APIs with source:
> - http://drupal.org/project/phonegap : Here you will get the complete
>     source code of Drupal PhoneGap app which runs of Android. iPhone and
>     BlackBerry. This source will help you to understand the PhoneGap
>     development techniques

Answer (score 1):

There are more books being published in 2012 on PhoneGap.  You can browse Amazon for some of the existing titles to date.  I agree that it has not been widely documented to date and there there were few in-depth sources of material to reference.

PhoneGap Beginner's Guide is a great starting point. It introduces WebKit browsers, cross platform mobile application development and the PhoneGap API in general. There are some pretty basic demos that you can code along with, and the supporting code is downloadable for free. The book was actually written by a member of the PhoneGap development team so it's legit. Another title with a more general intro is Mobile Application Development In The Cloud For Beginners: PhoneGap Build. This book is for a newb and it's newer so it has more references to the cloud version of PhoneGap.